# PHP echo in footer instead of body

Tags: php, html-table, echo, footer

Any one knows why my `$result` echo in footer instead of body?  Is it an html maybe div problem or PHP?

Here is a something similar to what I have:

```
    <?php
      // 1. Create a database connection
      $dbhost = "localhost";
      $dbuser = "tester";
      $dbpass = "12345";
      $dbname = "practice";
      $connection = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
      // Test if connection occurred.
      if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        die("Database connection failed: " . 
             mysqli_connect_error() . 
             " (" . mysqli_connect_errno() . ")"
        );
      }
    ?>

    <?php
    // 2. Perform database query
    $SQLstring = "SELECT *FROM user ORDER BY username";


    // Test if there was a query error
    $QueryResult = @mysqli_query($connection, $SQLstring)
    Or die("<p>Unable to execute query.</p>"
    . "<p>Error code " . mysqli_errno($connection)
    . ": " . mysqli_error($connection)) . "</p>";

    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE>
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php   
    //3. uses the mysqli_assoc() to print table
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr><th>Name</th><th>Address</th><th bgcolor='#0099FF'   
            align='left'>City</th><th bgcolor='#0099FF' align='left'>State</th></tr>";                  
    $num_results = $QueryResult->num_rows;

    for ($i=0; $i <$num_results; $i++) {
    // 3. Use returned data (if any)
    $Row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($QueryResult);  //associative array

    // output data from each row

    echo "<tr><td>{$Row['username']}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$Row['address']}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$Row['city']}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$Row['state']}</td>";
    </tr>";
    }

    // 4. Release returned data - close query
    mysqli_free_result($QueryResult);                           
    ?>
    </body>
    </html>

    <?php
      // 5. Close database connection
      mysqli_close($connection);
    ?>
```

Any ideas?  The table prints out fine no problem just not in the correct place on the site

Comment: can you take print-screen and upload it?

Comment: You're missing `</table>`, but I don't think that should cause this problem.

Comment: I don't see a `$result` or a footer in the code you posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 echo "<td>{$Row['city']}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$Row['state']}</td>";
    </tr>"; //You got an error here!
    }
```

I think you forgot to echo this line.

Comment: I suspect that's an error in copying to SO, otherwise the script wouldn't run at all because of the parse error.

Comment: thanks yes I see it now...oh my..forgot to close table for one..minor mistakes...thanks Darick

Answer (score 0):

you should get parse error but i could not point that

just try change this lines

```
 // output data from each row

echo "<tr><td>{$Row['username']}</td>";
echo "<td>{$Row['address']}</td>";
echo "<td>{$Row['city']}</td>";
echo "<td>{$Row['state']}</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
```